# Fixed navbar in Bootstrap 4 (2 rows)

Tags: html, css, menu, rows, center

I try to make a website in Boostrap 4, but I faced into a problem. I try to explain what I need.

A fixed to top navbar with 2 rows, but here comes the trick. Upper bar contains 2 logos (one on the left side and one on the right side, in the same row.

The second row contains only links, but ordered to center. Hopefully, my description not so misunderstandible.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post your code, or what changes you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but appears the standard navbar, if I try this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
<div class="row d-flex w-100 justify-content-between" >
    <img class="" style="width: 3rem" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Bootstrap_logo.svg/1024px-Bootstrap_logo.svg.png" />
    <img class="" style="width: 3rem" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Bootstrap_logo.svg/1024px-Bootstrap_logo.svg.png" />
</div>
<div class="row w-100 ">
    <ul class="d-flex list-unstyled mx-auto w-25 justify-content-between">
        <li class=""><a href="#" class="text-primary text-decoration-none ">My links</a> </li>
        <li class=""><a href="#" class="text-primary text-decoration-none ">My links</a> </li>
        <li class=""><a href="#" class="text-primary text-decoration-none ">My links</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div></nav>
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely, what I need! Only one thing, what I would like to know about this. In the second row, how could I do this without "list-looking" like a "classic" menu? Thank you very much!

Comment: try to replace the second row with this

<div class="row w-100 ">
        <ul class="d-flex list-unstyled mx-auto w-25 justify-content-between">
            <li class=""><a href="#" class="text-primary text-decoration-none ">My links</a> </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#" class="text-primary text-decoration-none ">My links</a> </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#" class="text-primary text-decoration-none ">My links</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

Comment: Looking much better! Thank you! I know, that makes the things harder, but what if I would like to add submenu in the second row? And appeared a problem. If I set less the height of the screen, the links in the second row becomes to unreadable.